# Cannot Set File/Image to RunTimeImageSource of Object Tracker

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am trying to dynamically create image targets at runtime. For that, I am capturing screen from vuforia AR camera and saving it in Application.persistentDataPath. Then I am creating a dataset trackable behavior following the script provided in [How to Create and Load Targets in Unity](https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/articles/Solution/how-to-create-and-load-targets-in-unity.html). 
My code for capturing the screen:

```
            var datapath = Application.persistentDataPath;
            
            datapath = Path.Combine(datapath, "image.jpg");
        
            int width = Screen.width;
            int height = Screen.height;
            Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

            // Read screen contents into the texture
            tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);
            tex.Apply();
            byte[] bytes = tex.EncodeToJPG();

            File.WriteAllBytes(datapath, bytes);
```

Code for creating trackable behavior:

```
            var objectTracker = TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ObjectTracker>();
            var runtimeImageSource = objectTracker.RuntimeImageSource;
            //Problem here
            bool result = runtimeImageSource.SetFile(VuforiaUnity.StorageType.STORAGE_ABSOLUTE, datapath, 0.15f, "Temp");
            // create a new dataset and use the source to create a new trackable
            var dataset = objectTracker.CreateDataSet();
            
            var trackableBehaviour = dataset.CreateTrackable(runtimeImageSource, "Temp");
            // add the DefaultTrackableEventHandler to the newly created game object
            trackableBehaviour.gameObject.AddComponent<DefaultTrackableEventHandler>();
```

This works well in my windows laptop but not on my android phone. After some debugging, I found out that `bool result` is being false and as a result, `var trackableBehaviour` is becoming `null`. 
 
**Edit:** The issue is not with write permissions. I can see the images getting saved at the persistentDataPath. The problem is with setting runtime image source to the saved image.

**Edit 2:** I tried using the texture directly instead of file like this `bool result = runtimeImageSource.SetImage(tex, 1f, "Temp");`. Still result is false. Therefore, I believe the issue is not with path resolution but something else.

Answer (score 0):

- First, Try to use VuforiaUnity.StorageType.STORAGE_APP instead of absolute.
- 2nd: try bool result = DataSet.Exists (String path, VuforiaUnity.StorageType storageType) and to debug which path will return true on phone
  [image]
- Application.persistentDataPath return the path without back slash, which means try to add"/image.jpg" instead of image.jpg, this may be the issue as well.

Comment: We cannot use DataSet.Exists as the dataset is getting created after
```bool result = runtimeImageSource.SetFile(VuforiaUnity.StorageType.STORAGE_ABSOLUTE, datapath, 0.15f, "Temp");```
This itself is causing the problem. Also, I am using Path.Combine which adds backslash out of the box. I can see images getting saved in the path (as I mentioned in the question) but the problem is setting it to a runtimeImageSource

Comment: Please look at Edit 2